# Is the page loading twice

Tags: angularjs

When the page loads, the alert fires twice. I am expecting it to fire only once. 
This is causing duplicate data insertion in an array inside init function.
Why is this happening. Is it something to do with the routing definitions. How to stop it.

**indexctrl.js:**

```
app.controller("indexctrl", function ($scope, $routeParams) {
var uPId = $routeParams.pqid;
var uCId = $routeParams.cid;

    if (uPId != null && uCId != null) {
        //some other code
    }
    else {
        alert('test');
        init();
    }
     var init = function(){
       //some code
    }
}
```

**app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'App/views/index.html',
        controller: 'indexctrl'
        })
        .when('/Index', {
            templateUrl: 'App/views/index.html',
            controller: 'indexctrl'
        })
        .when('/Index/pqid/:pqid/cid/:cid', {
            templateUrl: 'App/views/index.html',
            controller: 'indexctrl'
        })            
        .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);
```

Comment: all my resources was being fetched twice. You gave me a good idea: putting     <script>alert('test')</script> in several index.html locations. And I've found it: some resources were inside a ng-if directive (its an app inside an app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1. Check your controller is declared in html file as well.

2.The link which is referring to routes should be like this <a href="#/Index">

3.If your working with another frame works like ionic. it has aleardy angular.js file.so check how many time your loading script file.
```

Comment: Thank you. The controller was defined in the html too.

Comment: for me, the controller wasn't declared as well, but for some reason the html loaded 2x and thus the component.js 2x as well